# Scroll to top after Ajax content load

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Is there anyway that I can make it so the page will automatically scroll to the top after the content has loaded (via Ajax)?

This is the code I have for displaying the content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var my_layout = $('#container').layout();
    $("a.item_link").click(function () {
        $("#loader").fadeIn();

        feed_url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "URL=" + feed_url,
            url: "view.php",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#view-area").html(msg);

                $("#loader").fadeOut();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

So after the 'view-area' has loaded its content can I make the page auto scroll to the top?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just use the scroll function

```
scrollTo(0);
```

If you want the jquery, then [here is a good example with smoothing](http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/09/go-to-top-of-page-using-jquery/) :)

From the link:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
//nice and slow :)
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

To put it in your code

```
...
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#view-area").html(msg);
            $("#loader").fadeOut();
            //Put code here like so
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked perfectly! I just put the code in between $("#view-area").html(msg);
and
$("#loader").fadeOut();

and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Why it's not working on other selector? Like $('.section').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
But html, body selector working.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `$(window).scrollTop(0);`

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! Thnx for the great hint!:D

Answer (score 1):

All ajax requests have a callback argument so use `scrollTop(0)`.
Check the jQuery documentation on how to use ajax callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no callback, try to bind an event listener:

```js
document.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function(event) {
        event.composedPath().forEach(function(dom) {
            if (dom.classList && dom.classList.value === "classOfLoadedContent") {
                $(".div-to-be-scrolled").scrollTop($(".content").innerHeight());
            }
        });
    },
    true
);
```